# Which one is correct and perfect!

Tags: grammar, quotations

Which quote might be perfect one, or any suggestions

- There's no game **in** which I haven't won without losing.
- There's no game **in** which I haven't won without losing **it**.
- There's no game which I haven't won without losing.
- There's no game which I haven't won without losing **it**.

Comment: How about just  "There's no game I haven't won without losing"? Eight words and all the facts are in.

Comment: How about you tell us which you think is right and why. Plus, please note you have posted the same sentences twice.

Comment: I don't even understand what the message is. Do you mean that you are undefeated at every game in the world? It seems to me that you're trying to choose between a bunch of bad alternatives. Maybe you should say something like "I've never lost a game," if that's what you mean.

Comment: As a ["we don't need no education"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yj3dIo8PDjs) Brit, I thought I could handle multiple stacked negations, but the truth is I can't figure out what examples #1 and #3 might be intended to mean. And I can only get my head around #2 and #4 by understanding ***losing it*** as ***becoming angry or emotional***, which probably *isn't* what OP has in mind.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, #1 games never end in a draw, player either wins or loses. #3 I can't parse that either.

Comment: @Jasen: I suppose the most credible meaning (arrived at mainly by thinking about what would make sense in the real world, not by considering the syntax of the examples) would be *My ability to **win** a game of any given type always involves a learning process where I sometimes **lose***.

Comment: yes, we should ask the originator what they are trying to express, only then can a sentence be constructed.   @pok8_ what message are you trying to convey?

Comment: @Lambie - those are four different sentences.

Comment: Are you trying to express an idea like this: *I've never won a game that I didn't play at other times and lose*? If so, the problem with all your sentences is that it makes it sound like you both won and lost while playing a single instance of the game.

Comment: @Chaim it doesn't mean "I've never lost a game"! what i mean is i have always lost the game which i played at the first time or many more, but i had won it later

Comment: @FumbleFingers explained it correctly while mentioning @jansen! so, pleased see that kind of explanation

Comment: @Jasen @fumblefingers heard me correct! `My ability to win a game of any given type always involves a learning process where I sometimes lose.` ++ `i never gave up` ++ `i am a fighter` all these replicate the above quote.

Comment: @joiedevivre nope that's not what i am trying to express

Comment: @p0k8_ It looks to me, from your other comments here, like that's exactly what you were trying to express. But carry on.

Comment: As I understand it, [AlphaGo Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaGo_Zero) taught itself to become the strongest Go player in the world *by playing against itself*. I don't know how many such games it played *(millions?, billions?)* but arguably it (or at least, *half* of it) lost every one of those games. On the other hand, the "other half" actually *won* all of those games. If AlphaGo Zero ever gets speech output and tries to explain its training methodology, it'll probably be at least as convoluted as OP's attempts here!

Comment: I don't see how to read any of the original four sentences to mean that after losing a game you always improve at the game and later win. Maybe the trouble is with the word "without." If you instead say "There's no game at which have not eventually won after (or 'despite') first losing," that would retain something like the original phrasing but with the intended sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would think "there`s no game which I haven`t won without losing. Losing it means losing your mind or indeed get emotional or angry. You participate in a game, I don`t think you win in a game in English.

Comment: it doesn't always mean that.

Comment: You're right that native speakers usually ***win a game*** (transitive, no preposition), but [*For example, suppose you're playing a cointoss **game in which** you win if at any time heads come up.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cointoss+game+in+which+you+win%22)

Comment: In this case, with "losing it" I'd think you were referring to losing the game, not losing your mind.

Comment: @Zoot: The problem is that interpretation creates semantic dissonance. The initial reference *(there is no game)* refers to the game in the abstract - as in *Go is a challenging game* (***game** = all games of Go collectively).* But in something like *The first time I played chess I lost it*, we have to understand ***it*** as referring to *a single instance (one game) of chess*, which isn't really the same thing as what it syntactically refers back to.